# Code for factor with 4 levels in r programming

Tags: r

[image]

I would like to have the price range field to display as factor with 4 levels where 0=poor, 1=Normal, 2=Medium and 3=High. I have managed to create few other fields as factor with 2 levels. But don't know how to create a field as factor with 4 levels?
The data set is names as
mobile_price_classification
The uploaded screenshot is after the command:

```
> str(mobile_price_classification)
```

I want to have the price_range field as factor with 4 levels, where 0=poor, 1=Normal, 2=Medium and 3=High.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or data. Provide the output of `dput(mobile_price_classification)` instead.

Comment: Hi, please provide a reproducible example as @Phil has noted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't know how to provide a reproducible example :(

Comment: @Jack432 no need to be sorry just click William's link and follow the instructions there. I tried to help by making an example below. For starters following Phil's instructions and paste the result into your question will provide your data for others to troubleshoot on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to convert integer values directly into the factor labels using the `factor()` function.

```
df <- data.frame( price_range=sample(seq(0,3,1),20,replace = T),
                  x=rnorm(20,10,1))
df$price_range<- factor(df$price_range, labels = c('poor','normal','medium','high'))

df$price_range
[1] poor   poor   high   medium normal high   medium normal medium normal normal high   normal normal normal medium poor   poor   medium
[20] medium
Levels: poor normal medium high
```

Depending on your analysis you may want to consider adding the "order=TRUE" to the function call.  See `?factor` for more information.

Comment: Thank you. This was so quick and easy!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame( price_range=sample(seq(0,3,1),20,replace = T),
                  x=rnorm(20,10,1))
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(price_range=case_when(price_range==0 ~ 'poor',
                               price_range==1 ~ 'normal',
                               price_range==2 ~ 'medium',
                               price_range==3 ~ 'high'),
         price_range=factor(price_range, levels = c('poor','normal','medium','high')))
df2
```

Comment: Thank you. @Dave2e is the easiest one